# Differences between Chromium OS overlays?

Tags: compiling, cpu-architecture, chromium-os

In the [ChromiumOS source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays.git/+/master), there are currently the following build overlays offered:

- overlay-amd64-corei7
- overlay-amd64-drm
- overlay-amd64-generic
- overlay-amd64-host
- overlay-arm-generic
- overlay-beaglebone
- overlay-daisy
- overlay-daisy-drm
- overlay-emeraldlake2
- overlay-lumpy
- overlay-nyan
- overlay-panda
- overlay-parrot
- overlay-puppy
- overlay-raspberrypi
- overlay-stumpy
- overlay-tegra2
- overlay-variant-tegra2-dev-board
- overlay-variant-tegra2-dev-board-opengl
- overlay-variant-tegra2-seaboard
- overlay-waluigi
- overlay-x32-generic
- overlay-x86-alex
- overlay-x86-drm
- overlay-x86-fruitloop
- overlay-x86-generic
- overlay-x86-mario
- overlay-x86-pineview
- overlay-x86-wayland

While for some, the names give some indication of the target platform or included libraries, guessing what "waluigi" offers is quite a challenge.

Is there any online resource or person of knowledge who can give an overview of each build overlay?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any documentation. You can get clues by looking at what each overlay builds. In principle “waluigi” tells you everything you need to know, but this is quite an obscure and ungooglable name.

Comment: it behaves like the evil version of Mario's brother? :) OK, I can now dig into the builds to see what architecture they are targeting and I'll investigate how to analyse what packages they contain.